# Azure MFA Master Slave Server?

Tags: azure

I have created an Azure MFA solution with one Master server and 2 Slave servers.

I am looking into the possibility of setting a master slave server or is it not possible? the 2 slave servers are in separate locations and effectively on different networks.

Was just intrigued if it was possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Today there is no way to automate to make the Slave the Master unless you explicitly do so.  Now assuming your Master goes down, MFA will still work - just no new writes will occur (e.g. no new registrations).

With this said, I don't necessary understand why you would want a "Master of the Slave" server - as all Slaves should be ready to step up and become the Master.

When in doubt, follow [this thread by Shawn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a43f9a34-b761-41b1-b840-9244da0fb4c4/how-to-deploy-fault-tolerance-with-azure-mfa-server?forum=windowsazureactiveauthentication) on how to properly setup high availability for your Azure MFA Servers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.